# How to get sha1 hash from base64 encoded string in C#

Tags: c#, hash, base64, sha1

I have situation where I need to convert file to base64 and that is fine. After that I need to get sha1 hash from that base64 encoded string. I find lot of examples how to read the file to byte array and get sha1 hash from that but I need to get the sha1 hash from the base64 encoded string.

Comment: So are you trying to hash the string? if so you need to convert to a byte array using an encoding (e.g. System.Text.Encoding.UTF8), and then follow one of the byte array examples

Comment: @AlexM. : No, the OP states that he/she needs the hash of the Base64 string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're after?

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\file.txt");

var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

var base64Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String);

var sha1 = SHA1.Create();

var base64BytesHash = sha1.ComputeHash(base64Bytes);
```